# iOS - Sharing a video from share extension to my app reducing video quality

Tags: ios, swift, ios8-share-extension

While sharing video from share extension to my app, quality of video is getting reduced. This is not happening while selecting and uploading video directly through app.

I'm using below code to load video file from share extension.

```
func handleSharedFile() async {
    loader.startAnimating()
    let attachments = (self.extensionContext?.inputItems.first as? NSExtensionItem)?.attachments ?? []
    let contentTypes = [UTType.data, .url]
    for provider in attachments {
        for contentType in contentTypes {
            guard let loadedItem = await provider.load(type: contentType) else { continue }
            if let url = loadedItem as? URL {
                await MainActor.run {
                    if let uti = UTType(tag: url.pathExtension, tagClass: .filenameExtension, conformingTo: nil) {
                        let videoTypes = [UTType.movie, .video, .mpeg4Movie, .movie, .quickTimeMovie]
                        if videoTypes.contains(uti) {
                            if UIVideoEditorController.canEditVideo(atPath: url.path)  {
                                let editorController = UIVideoEditorController()
                                editorController.videoMaximumDuration = 90
                                editorController.videoPath = url.path
                                editorController.delegate = self
                                present(editorController, animated: true)
                            } else {
                                Task {
                                    let convertedUrl = await VideoConverterHelper().convertVideo(at: url, isShare: true)
                                    if let convertedUrl {
                                        // Here Upload video on server
                                        // For sample example here I'm playing video with AVPlayer
                                        self.playVideo(for: convertedUrl)
                                    } else {
                                        self.didTapCancelButton()
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return
            }
        }
    }
    loader.stopAnimating()
}

extension NSItemProvider {
    func load(type: UTType) async -> Any? {
        guard self.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(type.identifier) else {
            return nil
        }
        do {
            let item = try await self.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: type.identifier)
            if type == .data || type == .image {
                print("Type ", type.identifier)
                switch item {
                case let image as UIImage:
                    return image
                case let data as Data:
                    return UIImage(data: data)
                case let url as URL:
                    _ = url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
                    if  let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: url.path) {
                        return image
                    }
                    url.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
                    return url
                default:
                    return nil
                }
            } else if let url = item as? URL {
                return url
            }
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

You can download the complete sample project from [this link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1U2RPJkWhtFnsf5iI5C9jTqbae0LSumKp/view).